# Adding "Popularity" up by having duplicates in string (String Contains Name)

Tags: java

Having trouble figuring out exactly how to do this. Ive wrote 10 different things and worked on it for 8 hours and have yet to figure out how to get this to work. What I'm trying to do with this program is get a the persons name, friends name, persons age, friends age, and persons popularity (All of this from a .txt file with each line as : Michelle, 12/20/2008, Camilla) . I have gotten the persons name to output correctly, persons age to output correctly, and persons friend to output correctly. But having trouble with popularity and getting friends age from personsofinterest's age.

What I need help with :

1.Popularity points adding up and returned for each time the personOfInterest is in the name array. With the popularity I have went back and debugged it after i was getting 0 for every popularity for each person. And I got that it wasn't adding anything to the return, I tried many different ways but still could not figure it out.

2.Setting personOfInterest name to certain age to be used as friendsAge if the users friend is a personOfInterest already found age for.(All personOfInterest names in .txt field is someones friend)

```
friends_data.txt :

Michelle, 12/20/2008, Camilla

Bryan, 3/8/2007, Tom

Camilla, 6/7/2005, Michelle

Tom, 10/15/2007, Bryan

Charlotte, 3/2/2008, Michelle
```

I believe my code looks a little messy, started going back and throwing things together I thought would work.

Person Class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person {
    public String personsName;
    public String personsFriend;
    public String personsBirthday;
    public int personsPopularity;
    public int popularity = 0;
    public ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();


    public Person(String aName, String aFriend, String aBirthday) {
        personsName = aName;
        personsFriend = aFriend;
        friends.add(personsFriend);
        personsBirthday = aBirthday;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return personsName;
    }

    public String getFriendsName() {
        return personsFriend;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return personsBirthday;
    }

    public void getPopularityNumber(){
    for(int i = 0; i < friends.size(); i++){
        if (personsName.equals(friends.get(i))){
            popularity = 1 + popularity;
        }
        else
        popularity = popularity;
    }
System.out.println(popularity);
}

    public String getFriend() {
        return personsFriend;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        int MONTH = 0;
        int DAY = 0;
        int YEAR = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String[] dates = personsBirthday.split("/");
            String month = dates[0];
            String day = dates[1];
            String year = dates[2];
            MONTH = Integer.parseInt(month);
            DAY = Integer.parseInt(day);
            YEAR = Integer.parseInt(year);
        }

        int age = (2014 - YEAR);
        int moAge = (5 - MONTH);
        if (moAge < 0) {
            age--;
        }
        return age;

    }
}
```

Main File :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PersonTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //Get that file and start the scan on that broseph
        File inputFile = new File("friends_data.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

        //Set up an array for our Person objects
        final int SIZE = 5;
        Person[] personsOfInterest = new Person[SIZE];
        String[] friends = new String[5];

        //Lets get this i declared as 0 for our array!
        int i = 0;
        int popularity = 0;

        String person;

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] nameBirthdayname = line.split(", ");

            person = nameBirthdayname[0];
            String birthday = nameBirthdayname[1];
            String friend = nameBirthdayname[2];
            friends[i] = friend;
            personsOfInterest[i] = new Person(person, friend, birthday);

            i++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("New Person");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Persons Name : " + personsOfInterest[i].getName());
            System.out.println("Popularity : " + personsOfInterest[i].getPopularityNumber());
            System.out.println("Their age on May 1, 2014 : " + personsOfInterest[i].getAge());
            System.out.println("Persons Best Friend : " + personsOfInterest[i].getFriend());
            System.out.println("Best Friends Age on May 1,2014 : " + personsOfInterest[i].getName());
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");

        }
    }

}
```

Have Also Tried this for getPopularityNumber Method :

```
public void getPopularityNumber(String[] friends) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (personsName.equals(friends[i])) {
            popularity = 1 + popularity;
        } else
            popularity = popularity;
    }
    System.out.println(popularity);

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code will not compile. There is no getPopularityNumber() without args declared.

Comment: Yea, went back and did it where it would compile but gives me a wrong answer (popularity : 0) because for some reason its not adding friends names to the arraylist.

Comment: sorry but i see numerous flaws. in getPopularity method you loop through a person's friends list and increment popularity every time when a friend's name equals persons name, and else ovewrite it with its old value. But in your friends_data file none of persons has friends with an similar name, so it should naturally output 0. on the other hand, according to the logic of your constructor a person's friends ArrayList will always contain only one friend since just add a variable personsFriend to it and then never touch it again.

Comment: Just checking here, sorry new to java and trying to better understand everything. But Michelle is a friend twice in the friends spot taken from the .txt document? What do you mean by saying "none of  persons has friends with an similar name".